# Can't integrate Mingw to Notepad++

Tags: mingw, integration, notepad++, nppexec

I try to integrate my notepad++ to previously and successfully installed mingw application. I got help from this website:

http://iitdu.forumsmotion.com/t108-gcc-compiler-in-notepad

I took the code from that website as:

```
    // The script code, C source code compiling with GNU CC (GCC) in notepad++ (by                "NppExec" plug-in) and compressing with UPX...
//
// Enable? "//" signs remove in code line.
// Sample: C:\Program Files\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o $(NAME_PART)

YOUR_GCC\BIN\_PATH_HERE\gcc.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o $(NAME_PART)

// UPX Compress (with "--best, --ultra-brute" options)
// Enable? "//" signs remove in code line.
// Sample: C:\WINDOWS\system32\upx.exe --best --ultra-brute $(NAME_PART).exe

YOUR_UPX_PATH_HERE\upx.exe --best --ultra-brute $(NAME_PART).exe
```

and changed it as:

```
// The script code, C source code compiling with GNU CC (GCC) in notepad++ (by "NppExec" plug-in) and compressing with UPX...
//
// Enable? "//" signs remove in code line.
// Sample: C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o $(NAME_PART)

C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)" -o $(NAME_PART)

// UPX Compress (with "--best, --ultra-brute" options)
// Enable? "//" signs remove in code line.
// Sample: C:\upx.exe --best --ultra-brute $(NAME_PART).exe
C:\upx.exe --best --ultra-brute $(NAME_PART).exe
```

in my Nppexec plugin in Notepad++

And then when i try to execute my just above code i took a message like this:

```
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe "C:\Program Files\Notepad++\new  3.txt" -o new  3
Process started >>>
**gcc.exe: hata: 3: No such file or directory**
<<< Process finished.
C:\upx.exe --best --ultra-brute new  3.exe
Process started >>>
                       Ultimate Packer for eXecutables
                          Copyright (C) 1996 - 2013
UPX 3.09w       Markus Oberhumer, Laszlo Molnar & John Reiser   Feb 18th 2013

        File size         Ratio      Format      Name
   --------------------   ------   -----------   -----------
upx: new: FileNotFoundException: new
upx: 3.exe: FileNotFoundException: 3.exe

Packed 0 files.
<<< Process finished.
================ READY ================
```

In my mingw folder:

C:\mingw\bin\gcc.exe is ok

So why it can not find it i dont understand...

Comment: Try replacing `$(NAME_PART)` with `"$(NAME_PART)".exe`. But it's better to avoid including spaces in the names of your directories and/or files.

Answer (score 1):

My nppexec code for compiling within Notepad++ is

```
gcc $(FULL_CURRENT_PATH) -o $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)\$(NAME_PART).exe
```

That compile the file, create an .exe file in the same folder.

Hope that helps.